Calculate marketcap of a token in Dune Analytics
For an use case need to know the market cap of few coins across various blockchains. Using Dune analytics for this purpose but seems there is no direct way to know the market cap of coin in a blockchain.
Could anyone please help in how to query the market cap of a coin in Dune or is there any direct open source like Dune which could help in this manner?
For now my logic to calculate the market was :

Circulating supply * latest price

Circulating Supply : Minted Tokens−Burned Tokens−Locked Tokens
Also with this logic there are multiple assumptions and conditions to be taken care of, which all I am not aware of.
So would need help in how to approach this or query it in Dune?
